# Separating abbreviations of dates from month number

Tags: r, dplyr

I imported a csv file into R and have a column that is supposed to be for the month, but it contains the month in two different formats--month abbreviation and month number. It read in as a factor column so I can't figure out how to separate them.

I've tried mutate, separate, unite.... every dplyr command I can think of.

```
mutate(Pub.Mon, Mon=match(Pub.Mon,month.abb,nomatch=0))
```

I used this to create a new column that gives me the values of the month abbreviations as their month number, but can't figure out how to keep the month numbers from the original column in the new column

hoping to have a new column containing just the month number in it.

Comment: Please add some sample data using `dput()`.

Comment: You can keep only the numbers with `mutate(Pub.Mon, month_nr = reader::parse_number(Pub.Mon))`